# sphinx facet search: 'with_all' analogue for php/java

Tags: java, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, faceted-search

I have a doc set with MVA and i need to filer docs that have all required attrs (let's say, i need all 'news' doc having both 'java' and 'oracle' tags, assume i have tags ids).

at ThinkingSphinx (http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#filters) i found a usefull notaion:

> For matching multiple values in a multi-value attribute, :with doesn’t
>   quite do what you want. Give :with_all a try instead:

```
Article.search 'pancakes',   :with_all => {:tag_ids => @tags.collect(&:id)}
```

that, as far as i guess, allows to filter docs having ALL the provided attributes, instead of getting docs, having ANY of provided attr list for `SetFilterRange` usage.

Can anyone suggest soluion at least in terms of standard PHP interface? hope i'll be able to transform it to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple calls to setFilter are ANDed. Where as you note specifing multiple ids to one call are ORed.

```
$cl->setFilter('tag_ids',array($tag_id1));
$cl->setFilter('tag_ids',array($tag_id2));
$cl->setFilter('tag_ids',array($tag_id3));
```

Sorry cant help with the java syntax.

Comment: ahh, so simple! Thx! 
java just has wrappers for all those methods, particularly Client.SetFilter()